# R keeps crashing due to segfault

Tags: r, crash, segmentation-fault

R keeps crashing after about 10 minutes of fairly basic use returning the following error message.

[image]

R 3.0.1 GUI 1.61 on Mac OSX 10.8.4

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific code that lead to that?

Comment: 1) post to the r-sig-mac mailing list.  2) Make sure you've got a clean install, that your Mac's RAM has passed self-test, etc.